# Responsive converse.js UI

Tags: converse.js

I want converse.js such that it should work properly in mobile browser.

```
converse.initialize({
                    websocket_url: webSocketUrl, // ConnectionUrl
                    keepalive: true,
                    message_carbons: true,
                    message_archiving: 'roster',
                    //play_sounds: true,
                    auto_login: true,
                    jid: user,
                    password: password,                        
                    show_controlbox_by_default: false,
                    auto_list_rooms:true,
                    allow_logout: false,
                    allow_registration: false,
                });
```

Can we set in config?

Comment: especially it chat window doesn't work properly in android phone when you have vertical orientation

Comment: Is there any way to fix this issue. I am stuck with it last few days

Comment: it doesnt work with android 4.4 and 5.0 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the answer , i removed "this.chatboxviews.trimChats();" from $(window).on("resize") function in converse.js.The main issue was when we open the chat box it opens the android keyboard on focus which resizes the window and minimize the chat box ,where as in IOS it doesnt happen like that it doesnt open keyboard on focus. So, finding the main cause of the issue solved my problem.